# JQuery sometimes taking user to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an automatic slideshow looping through three different pictures. I have a **fadeOut** and **fadeIn** function, and an **await sleep** between the two so my **next picture** doesn't start fading in before my first picture **fades out**. This is the function:

```
$('#next').on('click', async function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     $('#im_' + currentImage).stop().fadeOut(600);
     await sleep(600);
     increaseImage();
     console.log(currentImage);
    $('#im_' + currentImage).stop().fadeIn(600);

   return false;
});
```

I have created a button that automatically clicks after **5 seconds**. When it clicks the image on the screen begins to **fadeOut**, waits until it has **faded out (`await sleep`)**, then **fadeIn** the next image.

My problem is that the code apparently randomly takes the user to the top of the page when a picture begins to **fadeIn.** It is not consistant, it sometimes happens on the first picture change, sometimes, could be the forth, 40th, anytime.

What is happening? I feel like I'm putting my **preventDefault/return** false in the wrong place, but if so why are they incorrectly placed? I have placed the **preventDefault** after line of code to see if it would change, but it has not.

This is my **sleep** function before you get mad at me for using **sleep** in javascript. Or do get mad at me because I'm still pretty new.:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

It's still a bare website, but you can see it here http://18.223.125.182/Dad_Website/index.html

Comment: Why exactly are you using `async/await`?  https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ offers a callback method that will execute once the animation is done.

Comment: Also are you preloading the images before you show them?  Otherwise there's the possibility if you are not setting a fixed image width/height that the page could shrink down, potentially appearing to go to the top, since the picture height is not taking up space.

Comment: @Taplar could you give me an example of the fadeOut callback method? I thought I tried it but it didn't actually do anything.
I wasn't preloading the images. I am now preloading them and it still appears to go to the top, albeit not as often as it was before.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sunhy18o/

Comment: Well, that was it. Thank you so much!